# DRF Serializer queryset filtering cross tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using Django REST Framework to configure Experiments that are carried out using different logins for different Services. How can I adjust the queryset of the set of BasicLogins depending on the chosen Service.

---

### Context

When configuring an Experiment, you chose a Service and multiple participating BasicLogins.
There are specific logins that are 1-to-1 related to a BasicLogin. Let's say we have BasicLogin, ALogin, BLogin and CLogin. It can happen that not all specific Logins exist for a given BasicLogin, e.g.

- BasicLogin **1**: has related Logins for Services **A** and **B**
- BasicLogin **2**: related Logins for Service **C**
- BasicLogin **3**: has related Logins for Services **A**, **B**, **C**

[image: Django REST Framework powered form to configure an Experiment]

BasicLogin has a supports method which looks up if a Service-specific login is related to it. If such specific Login object exists, the BasicLogin object supports the given Service.

```
class BasicLogin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    def supports(self, service_name):
        """ Returns whether a specific Login for a given service is available for a BaseLogin object."""
        if service_name == "a":
            return ALogin.objects.filter(basic_account=self) is not None
        elif service_name == "b":
            return BLogin.objects.filter(basic_account=self) is not None
        elif service_name == "c":
            return CLogin.objects.filter(basic_account=self) is not None
```

The ExperimentSerializer can easily be used to filter for enabled BasicAccounts.

```
class class ExperimentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    service = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        queryset=Service.objects.all(), many=False, view_name="service-detail"
    )

    basic_logins = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name="basiclogin-detail",
        many=True,
        read_only=False,
        queryset=BasicAccount.objects.filter(disabled=False)  
        # ^ Here is where I'd like to only show BasicLogins that support the service 
        # if possible by using the "supports" method of BasicLogin
    )
```

---

### Question

Can I filter the queryset of the BasicLogin `RelatedField` in the ExperimentSerializer to only contain BasicLogins with a corresponding specific Login for the given Service?

e.g. in the shown picture Service "**A**" is chosen, so only BasicLogins with a corresponding **A**Login should be shown.

---

*Here is a full-code example:*

```
from django.db import models


######## MODELS
### Service model
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)

### Basic login model containing general information
class BasicLogin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    def supports(self, service_name):
        """ Returns whether a specific Login for a given service is available for a BaseLogin object."""
        if service_name == "a":
            return ALogin.objects.filter(basic_account=self) is not None
        elif service_name == "b":
            return BLogin.objects.filter(basic_account=self) is not None
        elif service_name == "c":
            return CLogin.objects.filter(basic_account=self) is not None

### Specific models for different services
class ALogin(models.Model):
    a_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)  # exemplary

    basic_login = models.OneToOneField(BasicLogins, related_name="a_account")

class BLogin(models.Model):
    b_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)  # exemplary
    b_api_hash = models.CharField(max_length=64)  # exemplary

    basic_login = models.OneToOneField(BasicLogins, related_name="b_account")

class CLogin(models.Model):
    c_password = models.CharField(max_length=64)  # exemplary

    basic_login = models.OneToOneField(BasicLogins, related_name="c_account")

### Model combining the previous models
class Experiment(models.Model):
    basic_logins = models.ManyToManyField(BasicLogins, "experiments")
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name="experiments")


######## SERIALIZERS
class class ExperimentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    service = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        queryset=Service.objects.all(), many=False, view_name="service-detail"
    )

    basic_logins = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name="basiclogin-detail",
        many=True,
        read_only=False,
        queryset=BasicAccount.objects.filter(disabled=False)  # <--- Here is where I'd like to only show BasicLogins that support the service using the "supports" method
    )
```